# Disabling touchpad

Tags: touchpad, alps

I have a dell inspiron computer. I installed Ubuntu 11.10. I don't want to use its touchpad but I could not disable it. gconf-editor cannot be useful because touchpad is not seen in peripherals although it is properly working.

What should I do?

***My hardware:*** Alps Touchpad for Inspiron N5110

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:atareao/atareao
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install touchpad-indicator
```

*After installation, open the indicator from Applications -> Accessories -> Touchpad Indicator and set your touchpad in top-right*

This is the easiest way to disable.

Comment: It's apparent that the touchpad is not detected as such by the system. What would the indicator be good for?

Comment: My touchpad is properly working. I would like to disable it. Gaurav_Java's method works fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:atareao/atareao
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install touchpad-indicator
```

This didn't work for me until I unplugged and plugged my mouse back in... -12.04Beta

Works great now though!

Answer (score 0):

`touchpad-indicator` didn't work for me, so I wrote a little script to do it instead, and bound it to a shortcut key (Ctrl-F1).

it's a wee Python script, only a dozen lines, just sharing it in case anyone else finds it useful:

grab the code from:  https://gist.github.com/1336648

save as `/usr/local/bin/toggle_touchpad.py`, eg by opening

`gksudo gedit /usr/local/bin/toggle_touchpad.py`

and pasting the code in.

then, `sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/toggle_touchpad.py`

then, go to **settings-->keyboard-->shortcuts-->custom shortcuts**
add a new shortcut, call it eg *toggle touchpad on/off*, and give the command as `toggle_touchpad.py`.

Click OK, then click on the new row. Now click where it says "Disabed" in the new row, it will say it's waiting for a new shortcut key.  I chose `ctrl+F1`

**important:**  then log off and log back on again

voila!  feedback, comment, suggestions appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If the touchpad is still not working, go in bios menu and search touchpad and change the TP from Advanced to Basic. that was my experience to run my touchpad.